# Sonicwall Site to Site VPN no Traffic

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

I've set up a sonicwall site to site vpn between two Sonicwall devices - site A is a TZ210. They are connected as far as the VPN is concerned, but there is no traffic, or one way traffic at best.

Site A 192.168.15.0/24
Site B 192.168.7.0/24

Site B is able to ping the sonicwall at Site A, and send out pings to other IPs at Site A, but not get any replies.

Site A doesn't seem to want to send ANY traffic out at all. When I try to ping an address at site B, I get request timed out, but what's interesting is that the data inside Site A's sonicwall doesn't even show any packets going out - it stays at 0.

Here's where it gets interesting: I am able to ping addresses on Site B's network directly from the "Diagnostics" page of Site A's sonicwall with a response - just not from a PC on Site A's network.

I have updated firmware, restarted both devices, even gone as far as completely resetting and starting from scratch on Site A's Sonicwall. The access rules are correctly "auto-created" by the VPN setup on the sonicwall.

Access Rules Created:

Lan to VPN from Local Network to Remote Network ALLOW

VPN to Lan from Remote Network to Local Network ALLOW

I've double, triple, quadruple checked the address objects on both ends, both correct. I'm at a loss - everything seems to be configured correctly, so I don't udnerstand why there's no traffic!

Thanks for any feedback or help.

Comment: Could you please confirm that default gateway is configure properly at site A pc?

Comment: Also, what do your logs say? Is Site A purposely dropping traffic due to a configuration?

Comment: @Mr.lock : Yes, the default gateway is configured properly on the Site A PC. I checked for proxies or AD settings that would stop it, disabled windows firewall, and still nothing.

Comment: @RonMaupin The strange thing is, it's not showing up in the logs at all. Here's the network - PC > Trendnet TEG-448WS switch > Sonicwall . Is it possible that the switch is blocking the traffic?

Comment: Update - here's a tracert - 

Tracing route to 192.168.7.x over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.15.xx (An untangle network device)
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Comment: I disabled everything in the untangle network appliance and there is traffic. I will enable them one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: SOLUTION: OpenVPN on untangle had an overlapping subnet in it's address pools. Removed that and it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

**Solution:** Another web appliance in the network had OPENVPN installed with an overlapping subnet in the address pools, and the traffic wasn't getting past there - so it wasn't even making it to the sonicwall. I removed the overlapping subnet and traffic started passing through.

**Troubleshooting steps:**

- Checked sonicwall logs - no traffic was even being logged when ping
  or RDP attempts occurred through the computer.
- Did tracert - tracert showed first hop was going to Untangle web
  appliance, then not responding after that.
- Disabled all applications on Untangle and traffic went through -
  enabled one by one, testing after each one, and found traffic was
  blocked by Open VPN. Upon further research there was an overlapping
  subnet in OpenVPN and the traffic was being directed there and not
  sent to the gateway/Sonicwall.